# Submit form having file using java script submit button

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, form-serialize

java-script : 
i have a form that feed value to a controller via ajax call .
The form get serialized in ajax call and the controller return 'true' on success but  the problem is that my form have a file and the file can't be serialized . I am working out how i can receive the file in my controller using this ajax call .

```
function save()
{    
if(save_method == 'On_submitted') 
    {
          url = "<?php echo site_url('MyController/insertForm')?>";
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type: "POST",
                data:$('#form_name').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                    {
                        $('#modal_name').modal('hide');
                        alert('added successfully');
                        reload_table();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                        {
                            $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                            $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                        }
                    }
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error adding / update data');
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

                }
            });

    }
}
```

When i omit the input file fields than its working fine , the main problem is to send the file to controller via java-script . 
i have tries but i am don't know what is wrong and how can i do it .

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `dataType: "JSON"` if you sending files.

you can form `data` for request using (filesForm = name of form):

```
var formData = new FormData(document.forms.filesForm);
```

then add other keys:

```
formData.append("key", keyValue);
```

and to send this data, add this options to ajax call:

```
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData: false,
```

you need contentType = false (it will be multipart/form-data in fact) if you wish to upload files.
and final ajax call should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#result").html(result)
    },
    error: function (result) {
        $("#result").html(result)
    }
});
```

Comment: data : formData , where i will get the value in formData

Comment: from `var formData = new FormData(document.forms.<your_form_name_here>);`

it will get all data from your form, for example if your form have 2 file inputs and one text input, this formData object will have all this 3 arguments (to check use formData.get("input_name") )

Comment: Not working ! console.log(formData.get("input_name")); getting null  , what is "input_name" ? a attribute ???

Comment: you should have this form:

    <form name="**your_form_name_here**" >
     <input name="**input_name**" type="text" value="test">
    </form>

don't forget to change "name" attribute of _form_ and _input_

Comment: the ajax call didn't reach the controller . i have set the json status value TRUE in controller . but i can't retrieve it in my ajax call back ...  i mean the controller is not accessible  because  i am getting this as 
 undefined  "alert("status:"+data.status)"; in ajax success function  . i am getting value in ajax form console.log(formData.get("file"));

Comment: i don't know about php, in my case i'm using asp.net controller and get access to file from HttpContext.Request.Form.Files. But the main thing is: i send file + other data in ajax call, using this settings. The result request (i can check it in Network tab in ChromeConsole) will have contentType: multipart/form-Data.